# Error Handling in Go is returning empty error object in http response

Tags: go

I am create `API` in `go`. Everything is working fine only that when there is an error I want to show it to the user. I am using go's `errors` package.

Below is the `sample` code:

```
type ErrorResponse struct {
        Status string `json:"status"`
        Error  error  `json:"error"`
    }
err := errors.New("Total Price cannot be a negative value")
errRes := ErrorResponse{"ERROR", err}
response, errr := json.Marshal(errRes)
if errr != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return
}
io.WriteString(w, string(response))
```

The response I am getting is:

```
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "error": {} //why is this empty
}
```

error key should have string `Total Price cannot be a negative value`. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: You cannot send data after http.Error: See https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error. You should send `string(response)` instead of `http.StatusText(500)`. It _really_ helps reading all the documentation of any function used.

Comment: `if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
    return
}` I am not talking about this err. This error handling is for if `json.Marshal` fails.Please read the context properly before downvoting.

Comment: @Volker I have edited my question if you are confused. Please check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error types can't marshal themselves to JSON. There's a few ways to work around this. If you don't want to change your `ErrorResponse` struct then pretty much the only way is to define a custom `MarshalJSON` method for your struct where you tell the marshaler to use the string returned by the Error's `.Error()` method.

```
func (resp ErrorResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Status string `json:"status"`
        Error  string `json:"error"`
    }{
        Status: resp.Status,
        Error:  resp.Error.Error(),
    })
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/EgVj_4Cc3W

If you want to marshal errors into JSON elsewhere also. Then you could use a custom error type and define marshaling for that, e.g:

```
type MyError struct {
    Error error
}

func (err MyError) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(err.Error.Error())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/sjOHj9X0tO

Simplest (and probably the best) way is to just use a string in your response struct. It makes sense because the actual value you send in the http response is obviously a string, not an error interface.

```
type ErrorResponse struct {
        Status string `json:"status"`
        Error  string  `json:"error"`
    }
err := errors.New("Total Price cannot be a negative value")
errRes := ErrorResponse{"ERROR", err.Error()}
response, errr := json.Marshal(errRes)
if errr != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    // you should write something to responseWriter w here before returning
    http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
io.WriteString(w, string(response))
```

Note that in case the marshaling fails, you should still write some kind of response before returning.